# compare 2 serial time stamped data sets of different sizes MATLab

Tags: matlab, plot, serial-port

I have 2 data sets, U and V. U is a 2800x1 size array, and V is a 1829x1 size array. Both A and B have corresponding serial time arrays. The time arrays cover the same period of time and are at the same sampling rate, however one of the arrays has a few blips where there is no data.
What i want to do is plot U vs V for all matching serial time stamps, for example plot the U and V points which correspond to the time 735364.6 etc.

I am not sure if this can be done but would greatly appreciate any insight.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [intersect](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) to find values that are in both A and B, then plot the U and V data for those timestamps.

```
[C, ia, ib] = intersect(A, B);
figure
plot(C, U(ia), C, V(ib))
```